# How can you disprove the statement $4=5$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, real-numbers

I know this sounds **insane**. But bear with me, my friend said this to me with a straight face:

> Can you disprove the statement: $4=5$?

And I was like is that even a question, thats obvious, $5$ is $4+1$ and $5$ comes after $4$.

He was like: but you haven't still **disproved my statement**.

*Something like this went for around 30 minutes...and he wasn't happy at the end at all*

**Is he correct?** If not, how does one actually give a good sensible answer to such a person?

Comment: In mathematics you can't disapprove/prove anything without assumptions.

Comment: Actually $4 = 5$ in the trivial ring with one element, where $1 = 0$ there, but at least in $\mathbb{Z}$, it is assumed that $0 \neq 1$, and thus $4 = 5$ can't be true in it.

Comment: You need proper definitions for $4$ and $5$ before you could disprove his statement. As Weaam says, in trivial rings, it is possible to have $4=5$.

Comment: @Weaam really? never knew that. Where can I find that proof of 1=0?

Comment: @TheArtist I thought math was universal and elegant :/

Comment: Before you can prove or disprove anything you have to have a common definition of what a proof looks like, let alone having common definitions for the objects "4" and "5".

Comment: Ask your friend how does he prove his statement: $$4=5$$

Comment: Ask him to give you some examples of statements that he believes to be true and some that he believes to be false. Use those to discover the framework of proof and truth that he is using. It may be that he wil never be convinced by any argument - if you can identify that, then you can save yourself a lot of bother.

Comment: @M.S.E It is not "a proof of 1=0", it has nothing to do with arithmetic on integers, real numbers, rational numbers... It is what happens when you study arithmetic on a trivial ring, whose additive identity 0 and multiplicative identity 1 coincides. It all depends on what you assume you're working with. (As to the reference, see the very first example of rings in Dummit and Foote)

Comment: The correct way is "disprove", by the way.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily sound insane. On one hand, it is clear that $4\neq 5$. On the other, in math we like proofs of as much as possible. So maybe your friend is just wondering how something so simple and obvious could be proven, and what basic assumptions would be enough. My answer below shows how this goes.

Comment: @Aniket That's not the mathematical way. The lack of proof of the opposite could not be taken as a proof - that would just result in dumping the burden of proof back and forth.

Comment: @skyking You got me wrong. Normally these things are presented as fallacies. Things like 2=1 and 4=5. The way in which these are proved have some devastating and disastrous but subtle faults, not easy to notice.I just wanted to know if the OP's friend had any such proof, then it would be easier to tackle it. I am sure that he didn't mean to question the basic assumption of the natural number system like "Why does 5 come after 4? 5 should be equal to 4." Something like that.

Comment: This is a pretty good question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you :) Will love to hear your approach.

Comment: @M.S.E: Not sure I have an approach -- more or less I stand behind Lee Mosher's answer (and the comment thereto). Of course this only transforms the question to "how do we know the successor function is injective?", which is an axiom in PA. At the elementary-school level one might argue that subtracting 1 from equal numbers must give equal numbers (by imagining a paring between two sets and repairing it after one element is removed from each), but whether that clarifies or confuses further is debatable.

Answer (score 33):

Hold up 4 fingers on your left hand. Hold up 5 fingers on your right hand (yes, count your thumb as a finger). Show that no matter how you try to pair them off, there's always one left over on your right hand. For added effect, make it the middle finger.

Comment: That just made my morning....

Comment: Personally, I believe that all previous $24$ up-votes were given for the last statement, and for the last statement only. I cannot prove nor disprove this conjecture, but I have added $1$ myself in order to support it.

Comment: HAHAHA! I'm gonna save this and try this when I meet him again (hopefully I'll get the proper timing and chance)

Comment: If you're envisaging "show that no matter how you try to pair them off" to be done by an exhaustive search, then that sounds feasible for $4\ne 5$, but I wouldn't want to attempt to prove $30\ne 31$ that way. Surely we can do better!

Comment: I don't think this amounts to a proof (and I *don't* mean because it isn't sufficiently rigorous). What you've said amounts to "try to show they're equal, observe that your attempts fail, and conclude that the claim is false." A skeptical person might be concerned that there is some clever way to make the fingers line up that they just didn't think of. There **are** lines of reasoning to convince them, and I think they're what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

Subtract 4 from both sides of $4=5$, yielding $0=1$. Now $0$ is defined to be the number such that $0+x=x$ for every $x$ and $1$ the number such that $1\cdot x = x$ for every $x$. But with that definition of $0$ we get that $0\cdot x = (0+0)\cdot x = 0\cdot x + 0\cdot x$, so $0\cdot x =0$ for every $x$. So since $1$ is the multiplicative identity (the property described above), but $0$ behaves differently multiplicatively, they can't be equal.

Comment: Thank you, this is lovely :)

Comment: @M.S.E You're welcome! Let me know what your friend's response to this argument is, please.

Comment: (Hi Quinn.) I think this just obfuscates the original problem. The conclusion rests on "0 behaves differently multiplicatively from 1, so they're distinct." However, if you want to claim that 0 isn't the multiplicative identity, that boils down to proving that some numbers aren't equal to each other.

Comment: I suppose you're right, @MikeHaskel. It's just gotta be an axiom that $0\neq 1$.

Comment: Then again, @MikeHaskel, for this argument to work all one has to believe is that there's at least one number different from zero.

Answer (score 6):

A good sensible answer would have to be based on some assumptions, i.e. on a set of axioms. The simpler the axioms, the better, but you cannot get away from some kind of assumptions or axioms.

In truth, this situation holds for **any** theorem of mathematics, not just the theorem $4 \ne 5$. In calculus, for example, the assumptions one often uses are the axioms for the real numbers; from those, one can produce a proof of any theorems you run across in a calculus text.

In simple integer arithmetic, the assumptions one often uses are the [Peano Axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms). It would be straightforward, albeit perhaps a little tedious, to produce a proof that $4 \ne 5$ using the Peano axioms.

One thing that happens with proofs is that in addition to having a long tedious formal proof, you also try to boil the proof down into basic intuitive statements. I'll venture to guess that in the end, the formal proof using Peano's Axioms that $4 \ne 5$ will probably boil down to exactly what you said, "$5$ comes after $4$".

Comment: I don't think it is that tedious to prove that $4 \neq 5$ with Peano. This follows immediately from $m=n \Leftrightarrow S(m)=S(n)$ and $0$ is not a successor: $$4=5 \Rightarrow S(3)=S(4) \Rightarrow 3=4 \Rightarrow ... \Rightarrow 1=0 \Rightarrow 0=S(0)$$

Answer (score 3):

From the point of view of a non-mathematician, but one who is forced to use some degree of logical and internally consistent thoughts, arguments, and communications with other humans on a daily basis, before proving any kind of relation between any two "objects", it is usually required that an agreement exists on what these objects are, or on what we agree ("rightly" or "wrongly") that they are. So I suggest that you and your friend sit down and agree on a common definition of what the visual symbol "$4$" means/represents, what the visual symbol "$5$" means/represents, and what the visual symbol "$=$" means/represents.

After that, I feel that you will be able to debate more fruitfully whether the relation $4=5$ is valid or not, given your agreed upon definitions.

As an example, just last night I agreed with a friend that "$4$" represents "moving away from the center of earth's gravity", "$5$" represents "hot chocolate" and "$=$" means "not the same thing". We also have reached agreement on the meaning of all words used in the above definition. Then we were able to reach the conclusion that $4=5$ is a useful compact expression of a relation that actually holds.

Comment: +1 Thank you, this is the best way I should have **started** the discussion with my friend :)

Comment: @M.S.E Glad I could shed some layman's light on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

> *Something like this went for around 30 minutes...and he wasn't happy at the end at all.*
>
> Is he correct? If not, how does one actually give a good sensible answer to such a person?

At some point in a child's life, they learn the word "why". They learn that they can basically question everything. When justification is given for an answer, that justification can be questioned as well. In these situations, a "sensible answer" doesn't exist because the person you are talking to isn't sensible.

That said, you friend might actually be sensible. So here is what I would do.

First you need to agree on a set of facts that don't need justification. A proof is something that goes from something that is know to be true to the statement you want to show is true. If you can't, for example, agree on the definition of natural numbers, then it isn't really possible to write down any proofs involving the natural numbers. So, you need to find common ground. If your friend refuses to accept anything as true, then no proof exists.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much. I love the part "A proof is something that goes from something that is known to be true to the statement you want to show is true". I'm gonna quote this to him soon :)

Answer (score 0):

It's all about definitions. I suggest you review (a) the definitions of [mathematical equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)). "$x=y$" has different meanings depending on context -- in this case, you are dealing with (b) an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation):

> In mathematics, an equivalence relation is the relation that holds between two elements if and only if they are members of the same cell within a set that has been partitioned into cells such that every element of the set is a member of one and only one cell of the partition. The intersection of any two different cells is empty; the union of all the cells equals the original set. These cells are formally called equivalence classes.

Since 4 and 5 are different, they occupy separate uniquely-partitioned cells in the set of integers (or of reals or rationals, etc). How do we know that 4 and 5 are different? They have different properties: 5 is prime, 4 is not; 5 is odd, 4 is not; 4 is a perfect square, 5 is not, etc. Since they are different, 4 and 5 cannot occupy the same cell in the set, so the statement $4=5$ does not satisfy the definition of an equivalence relation.